# Why do some public hosts resolve to 127.0.0.1?

Tags: dns, localhost, malware

I was to check this URL:

> http://geotool.servehttp.com

Is this some sort of suspicious behavior? I can't understand.
My local [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) (I am using Windows 7 - 64 bit) shows nothing about this domain.

I also made an online [whois](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHOIS) query on it and there I found 127.0.0.1 as its IP address!!!
What's the magic behind this?

**Edited**
When I point to this URL, using my browser, the localhost ([WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) server) homepage loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Four Years** ago, I asked this question and now, I am posting an answer to it for any further reference.

## DNS Information

```
TXT Record:

AUTHORITY
servehttp.com.  IN  SOA nf1.no-ip.com. hostmaster.no-ip.com.
```

This text record tells us that the domain `geotool.servehttp.com` probably belongs to `no-ip.com`.

Visiting internet website for http://no-ip.com (which currently redirects to `https://noip.com`), a simple slogan tells us everything:

> Create an easy to remember hostname and never lose your connection again.
>
> Our Dynamic DNS solution makes it easy to remote access any internet connected device.

That is, a [Dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) service. It helps you reach your local hosted application or network through internet by assigning a dns name to your dynamic always changing ip address.

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

Whoever configured the DNS records for geotool.servehttp.com pointed that subdomain name to 127.0.0.1.

It is not usual to point a public hostname to a private IP address, but it is possible.

Here are the results from `dig +trace geotool.servehttp.com A`:

```
geotool.servehttp.com.  60      IN      A       127.0.0.1
servehttp.com.          86400   IN      NS      nf3.no-ip.com.
servehttp.com.          86400   IN      NS      nf4.no-ip.com.
servehttp.com.          86400   IN      NS      nf2.no-ip.com.
servehttp.com.          86400   IN      NS      nf5.no-ip.com.
servehttp.com.          86400   IN      NS      nf1.no-ip.com.
;; Received 151 bytes from 83.222.240.75#53(83.222.240.75) in 153 ms
```

Comment: Yes, I know. but why? whats the magic behind this and whats the benefit?

Comment: There's no magic behind it. When your local DNS resolver goes to find out the IP address of "geotool.servehttp.com", it stores "127.0.0.1" and then it tries to connect to "127.0.0.1". It's like asking someone how to get to the grocery store, and instead of them telling you to go to Main Street, they tell you to go into your kitchen. So, you go to your kitchen, even though that's not where the store actually is.

Comment: I know what DNS is. I just wanted to know why should one do this. this is what I call magic, because there is certain benefit behind that for him to do so.

Comment: From what I have seen, some people will point a domain name to localhost to create the DNS equivalent of "dev/null".

Comment: This is useful for testing local deployments (that depend on domain or subdomains.)

Say I have a server running on my machine. I can use servehttp.com:8080 and it should show my local deployment. Now i can also use subdomains like customer1.servehttp.com:8080 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The question asks 'why', so I would like to share my reason.

I wrote a proxy software called `vproxy`, so I bought domain `vproxy.cc`.
In the software it runs dns health check periodically to see if the dns server is still available (otherwise it will stop sending dns requests to that server).
The health check is enabled by default, so I have to choose a domain which simply does nothing but returning a constant A record (ipv4 address).

So here comes `127.0.0.1.special.vproxy.cc`, which resolves to `127.0.0.1`. The domain and address are hardcoded into the software as the default dns health check settings.

Using `127.0.0.1` is simply because it's a loopback address and if someone accidently send traffic to this domain/address, he/she would be sending to local and would not cause any trouble for other people.
And the reason I'm not choosing other `127.x.y.z` ips is because they are not so well known as `127.0.0.1` do. Most people don't know that `127/8` are all loopback addresses, but people do know `127.0.0.1`.

And for `geotool.servehttp.com`, maybe the maintainer simply want the same thing as I do? Just some const address which is choosen to be `127.0.0.1`.